# I can't minify images with gulp-imagemin because of thumbs.db

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I cant minify my images because of thumbs.db file, when I try to minify my images, I get a permission error which looks like this:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\template\dist\img\Thumbs.db'

I get it why it does this but I don't know how to prevent this.

Edit 1: gulp snippet

```
gulp.task('imageMin', () =>
  gulp.src('src/img/*')
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
);
```

Comment: Have you tried running with `--verbose`? Looking through gulp-imagemin's [source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/blob/master/index.js#L50) a bit it seems like it should skip any files that aren't a recognized image type.  So, *maybe* `--verbose` will shed some light on the issue? **Edit:** Probably scratch that actually, this is probably related to [gulp-]imagemin not having read permissions for that file, but trying to read it anyway...

Comment: Could you post the relevant snippet from your gulpfile?

Comment: `gulp.task('imageMin', () =>
  gulp.src('src/img/*')
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
);
`

Answer (score 2):

From your gulpfile, if `thumbs.db` is causing issues when an attempt is made to read it, it looks like you'll have to filter it out in your `gulp.src` step, try updating your gulpfile to exclude `thumbs.db` like so:

```
gulp.task('imageMin', () => gulp.src('src/img/*.!(db)')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')));
```

The (probably cleaner) alternative would be to make sure Thumbs.db was never present in your img folder, but that might be easier said than done.